# How to escape characters like colon : and comma , in for loop?

Tags: bash, rsync, cp

I have a file named "blocked.txt" which contains name of 4000 files like below:

```
1502146676.VdeI4b5c5cbM804631.vps47619.domain.local:2,
1502146676.VdeI4b5c5cdM808282.vps47619.domain.local:2,
1502146677.VdeI4b5c5d3M192892.vps47619.domain.local:2,
1502146677.VdeI4b5c5d7M213070.vps47619.domain.local:2,
1502146677.VdeI4b5c5e5M796312.vps47619.domain.local:2,
1502146678.VdeI4b5c5efM412992.vps47619.domain.local:2,
1502146678.VdeI4b5c5f1M613275.vps47619.domain.local:2,
1502146679.VdeI4b5c5f8M11301.vps47619.domain.local:2,
1502146682.VdeI4b5c66dM115848.vps47619.domain.local:2,S
1502146682.VdeI4b5c676M608733.vps47619.domain.local:2,
1502146685.VdeI4b5c69aM1652.vps47619.domain.local:2,
....
 ....
```

i ran below command on shell to copy the files to /tmp/backup directory

```
for i in `cat blocked.txt`; do cp -f  "${i}" /tmp/backup/ ; done
```

but this gives me error "do you want to overwrite ? y/n" even though i have used  -f with cp

Any idea whats wrong in the command ?

Comment: I have used your code and I can not reproduce (using linux and bash). Files are correctly copied and no error message when we try this several times

Answer (score 1):

You likely have an alias,

```
alias cp="cp -i"
```

or function

```
cp () {
    command cp -i "$@"
}
```

that interferes.

To solve this, simply use `command cp` instead of just `cp`:

```
while read -r name; do
    command cp "$name" /tmp/backup
done <blocked.txt
```

Or specify the full path to `cp`:

```
while read -r name; do
    /bin/cp "$name" /tmp/backup
done <blocked.txt
```